# JQgrid multiple search not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid in my page where I gave search options as below. But I cant get any multiple search active. The search pop up only has single search. The "ADD", "OR" drop down and the 'plus' icon are not coming. FYI I am using IBM Domino. Why is it so?

Code :

```
$("#...").jqGrid ({
  ...
  ...
  search : {
    caption : 'Filter',
    multipleSearch : true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set the multiple search on your [`navgrid`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) setup like:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false
}, {}, {}, {}, {
    multipleSearch: true,
    multipleGroup: true
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LTPT5/